# Why is this a legal release of an object? (iOS Memory Management)

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm just beginning to learn about proper releasing of objects for memory management in iOS.  My biggest question is based on the below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    self.title = @"My View Controller";  

    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd   
                             target:self   
                             action:@selector(doSomething)];  
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;  

    [item release];  
}
```

Ok, I see that UIBarButtonItem has been created (alloc).  Now, it is set to the `rightBarButtonItem` property in the following line:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Directly after this line, the item gets released.

```
[item release];
```

I assume that the item is copied into the rightBarButtonItem but how can I know this happens.  If it gets passed by reference, I would have a problem wouldn't I?  Can someone clarify what is going on here and why releasing the object is legal?  Much thanks.

Comment: Don't start where you're starting. Start with [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). I recommend checking Apple's documentation on ARC, if you have access to it, though that link will give you all the details.

Comment: How come?  I actually think explicit memory management is great for my learning.

Comment: Because explicit memory management of Objective-C objects is obsolete. You're spending time investigating questions that go away with the move to ARC. ARC brings different questions, and those are the ones you should be asking.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `rightBarButtonItem` was declared `retained`. (See the [UINavigationItem Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItem))

When you declare a property as retained:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem
```

You are saying that when you'll change its value `aNavItem.rightBarButtonItem = aNewItem` you will send a `[aNewItem retain]` message.

Therefore you can safely release it afterwards (as it is retained by the `rightBarButtonItem`)

For more information, I highly recommend you take a look (monthly just to get used to it until it becomes second nature) at the [Apple Memory Management Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 2):

When it is assigned to the rightBarButtonItem, it is retained.  It is important to remember that release does not 'get rid of an object' - it just decrements the retain count.  Only when the retain count reaches 0, does an object get deallocated.

In this case, when you assign item to rightBarButtonItem, it has its retain count incremented to 2.  Next, when you release it, the retain count gets decremented to 1.  When the navigation controller goes away, this will go to 0 (and then your item will be deallocated).

This works as long as it is a property of type retain:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem
```

You can look at the header of the API to determine what type of property you are assigning to.

Answer (score 0):

The key here, Ryan, is that the rightBarButtonItem is retaining the object that is stored in it.

The answer above is quite good. The one thing I would add is that you can also look in the docs where the property is described and it says @property(nonatomic,retain).  SO, if you're not comfortable reading header files, it's in the docs also.